# Why does the interpretor not see the call?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this (VUE) Code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="kalender">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <div id="calendarbody" onload='refresh(new Date())'>
        <div id="month">
            <button id="current">aktuelles Datum</button>
        </div>
        <div id="days"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="messages"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      name: 'kalender',
      props: {
          msg: String,
          startDate: new Date()
      }
  }

  function refresh(date) {
      var month = date.getMonth();
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var days = document.getElementById("days");
      var prevmonthDays = 2; //Anzahl der Tage des vorigen Monats, die angezeigt werden sollen
      var curmonthDays = 31; //Anzahl Tage des aktuellen Monats
      var nextmonthDays = 2; //Anzahl anzuzeigende Tage des nächsten Monats
      var day = document.createElement("div");
      var m = 0;

      for (m = 1; m < prevmonthDays; m++) {
          day = document.createElement("div");
          day.className = "day";
          day.innerHTML = "m";
          day.id = "" + m + month + year;
          days.appendChild(day);
      }

      for (m = 1; m < curmonthDays; m++) {
          day = document.createElement("div");
          day.className = "day";
          day.innerHTML = "m";
          day.id = "" + m + month + 1 + year;
          day.style.color = '#006600';
          days.appendChild(day);
      }

      for (m = 1; m < nextmonthDays; m++) {
          day = document.createElement("div");
          day.className = "day";
          day.innerHTML = "m";
          day.id = "" + m + month+2 + year;
          day.style.color = '#666666';
          days.appendChild(day);
      }
  }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
  h3 {
    margin: 40px 0 0;
  }
  
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #42b983;
  }
  
  .day {
      width: 96px;
      height: 90px;
      background-color: aqua;
      border: solid grey;
      color: dimgrey;
      font-size: 48px;
      align-content: center;
  }

  #days {
      display: flex;
      width: 700px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      position: absolute;
      left: 25%;
      top: 300px;
  }
</style>
```

and receive the error message "refresh is defined but never used!"

I tried to fetch the onLoad-Event before the call is made, but anyways the precompiler igneres everything written in the code section and does not find the relations.

Trying to access the DOM from inside of the code fails as well.

What did I miss out?

Comment: That warning would be coming from some tool you're using, like ESLint or TypeScript or similar; not from the JavaScript engine (which doesn't care if you define things you don't use).

Comment: I can't speak for Vue, but in HTML, `div` elements never fire a `load` event.

Comment: In vue.js methods are defined as https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#methods, inside `methods` object in your exported object.